# Android RadioButton not grouped together programmatically

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

I'm creating `RadioButton`s programmatically

```
RadioGroup group = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.grp); 
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  RadioButton btn = new RadioButton(this); //this is an Activity
  btn.setText(String.valueOf(i));
  group.addView(btn);
}
```

However, my `RadioButton`s are not grouped together - I can check all of them, they act 
independently.

The documentation only states that the `RadioGroup` is used to *create a multiple-exclusion scope for a set of `RadioButton`s.*

Or do I have to manage my `RadioButton`s' checked state manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every `RadioButton` requires a unique ID so, that `RadioGroup` can differentiate them. Try this.

```
RadioGroup group = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.grp); 
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  RadioButton btn = new RadioButton(this);
  btn.setId(i); // <- set ID
  btn.setText(String.valueOf(i));
  group.addView(btn);
}
```

Comment: My eyes must have glazed over setting of ID in the each and every online code sample I've seen, thanks!